# How To Configure Network Print Server

Tags: networking, printer, release-hera

I'm new to elementary OS.  Have successfully installed elementary OS onto 
PC and have Internet working. Plus local printing to Canon MX320.

Now I am wanting to use elementary OS to provide a Network Print Server function, so other PCs on the local network can remotely print to the Canon MX320 connected to the elementary OS PC (via USB).  Of course, the elementary OS PC will be need to be powered on.

Does elementary OS 5.1 Hera support Network Print Server functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Great you got new to elementary OS.

Elementary OS being a Linux like any other bassed under Ubuntu (Hera is bassed on version 18.04 LTS) you can perfectly use `CUPS` **(Common UNIX Printing System)** to make your print server.

I invite you to follow [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html) to help you configure your print server.

if you have problems you may need to install the drivers for CANON printer `cups-backend-bjnp`

```
$ sudo apt install cups-backend-bjnp
```